# jQuery check if Cookie exists, if not create it

Tags: jquery, cookies, if-statement, referrer, isnull

I cannot get this code to work I must be missing something pretty simple.  I am trying to check to see if a Cookie exists, if it does {do nothing} if it doesn't {create it}.  I am testing the cookie by including an alert on a page.  Basically I do not want the cookie to keep re-creating with a referral url, I am trying to grab only the FIRST referred URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  if ($.cookie('bas_referral') == null ){
   var ref = document.referrer.toLowerCase();  
   // set cookie  
   var cookURL =  $.cookie('bas_referral', ref, { expires: 1 }); 
  } 
 });
```

Displaying the current cookie contents:

```
    // get cookie  
    alert($.cookie('bas_referral'));  

    // delete cookie  
     $.cookie('bas_referral', null);
```

Comment: Appears to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wxFvG/. Have you included the `$.cookie` plugin source code in your page?

Comment: Are you opening the page by HTTP? (and thus not from local disk file system) What cookie plugin are you using? What time unit is the expires value? Seconds? So, it expires in 1 second?

Comment: I am using the jquery.cookie.js plugin and my alert displays the previous URL I was on, so I believe the cookie is being created.  HOWEVER, if I were to go to different pages throughout the site, the alert displaying the cookie URL will change, it shouldn't being I set an IF-Statement.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I think the bulletproof way is:

```
if (typeof $.cookie('token') === 'undefined'){
 //no cookie
} else {
 //have cookie
}
```

Checking the type of a null, empty or undefined var always returns 'undefined'

**Edit:** 
You can get there even easier:

```
if (!!$.cookie('token')) {
 // have cookie
} else {
 // no cookie
}
```

`!!` will turn the [*falsy* values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) to false. Bear in mind that this will turn `0` to false!

Comment: WARNING: typeof null === 'object' as Dan comments below.

Comment: this is the correct answer for the given question, @foo!

While I tested the code, the true false context was vice versa:

if (!!$.cookie('token')) {
// have cookie
} else {
// no cookie
}

Comment: woah! it checks null, empty and undefined! Didn't know there's a shorter way to check those three before. Nice

Comment: what if the value of the cookie was `false`? probably better to check `null` and `undefined`

Comment: @foo the shorter answer isnt working for me. it is showing the opposite as to what the answer says - for me at least!

Comment: The short answer with `!!` will trigger the eslint style check error: `no-extra-boolean-cast`. Better to use the typeof check, just in case

Comment: My non-existing cookies were "null" but not "undefined"

Comment: hey @WebMW see the **Edit** section:
`!!$.cookie('token')` returns `false`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script> add this in your header to make sure it works

Answer (score 26):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     var CookieSet = $.cookie('cookietitle', 'yourvalue');

     if (CookieSet == null) {
          // Do Nothing
     }
     if (jQuery.cookie('cookietitle')) {
          // Reactions
     }
 });
```

Comment: i don't know why but this is setting a cookie, not checking if one exists, very strange!

Comment: var CookieSet = $.cookie('cookietitle', 'yourvalue'); not works on my pc, what can be the reason? I'm using although jquery 1.9.1 library.

Comment: Hmm I found the reason; I didn't have been installed the plugin from GitHub, I realised this was a native function. People who read this should download the plugin from (thank you @Kazar) : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 10):

I was having alot of trouble with this because I was using:

```
if($.cookie('token') === null || $.cookie('token') === "")
{
      //no cookie
}
else
{
     //have cookie
}
```

The above was ALWAYS returning false, no matter what I did in terms of setting the cookie or not. From my tests it seems that the object is therefore undefined before it's set so adding the following to my code fixed it.

```
if($.cookie('token') === null || $.cookie('token') === "" 
    || $.(cookie('token') === "null" || $.cookie('token') === undefined)
{
      //no cookie
}
else
{
     //have cookie
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cookie after having checked if it exists with a value.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){            
      if ($.cookie('cookie')) { //if cookie isset
         //do stuff here like hide a popup when cookie isset
         //document.getElementById("hideElement").style.display = "none";
      }else{
         var CookieSet = $.cookie('cookie', 'value'); //set cookie
      }       
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this very simple:

```
            var cookieExist = $.cookie("status");
            if(cookieExist == "null" ){
                alert("Cookie Is Null");

            }
```