# variable scope issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application, originally those codes works:

```
var htm = "<div> My content </div>";   
$("#divprint").html(htm);
window.setTimeout('window.print()', 4000);
```

however, when I try to wrap it within an if statement, it won't print:

```
var canprint= $.cookie("actionprint");  
alert("I am outside " + canprint);
if(canprint == null){
    alert("I am inside");
    var htm = "<div> My content </div>";
    window.setTimeout('window.print()', 4000);
}
```

when I run this codes, I only got first alert:  "I am outside null"

As javascript's scope is function level, I am wondering, why that if failed?

Comment: I don't see any function definition in your code. Btw, `console.log(typeof canprint, canprint);`

Comment: did you forget a double quotation mark on the declaration of variable htm?

Comment: Is your code missing the closing quotes like your post is?

Comment: `$.cookie()` for the props that don't exist returns `undefined`.

Comment: @BlackSheep - That i think is the actual reason

Comment: That's not the reason. `null == undefined` is true, so it should go into the `if`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, why you removed the " at the end of </div> ?

Comment: Hi BlackSheep, I've tried canprint ==undefined, doesn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  As weird it is:

Firstly, I tried to print out:

```
  console.log(typeof canprint, canprint);
```

amazingly, result is:

```
string null
```

so, I changed to if condition to:

```
if(canprint == "null")
```

then it can goes inside that if.

Though this is working, does anyone who can explain what has happened?
This is really out of my expedition.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the if statement like,

```
if (!canprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote and parenthesis from setTimeout function

```
window.setTimeout(window.print, 4000);
```

And use something like this: [jQuery check if Cookie exists, if not create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362688/jquery-check-if-cookie-exists-if-not-create-it)

```
var CookieSet = $.cookie('cookietitle', 'yourvalue');

     if (CookieSet == null) {
          // Do Nothing
     }
     if (jQuery.cookie('cookietitle')) {
          // Reactions
     }
```

Comment: Although this is a reasonable suggestion, it isn't necessary; the original call will also work. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. It sets the cookie before checking if it's already set.