# Is there a way to disable href link on click for n days use cookies in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

Is there a way to use cookies to disable a link after click for 5 days and be active again until click then disable for 5 days ...etc

I have use this for disabling but refreshing page link is active again. I was just thinking using $_user cookie I might be able doing this my problem is getting things together. Google a lot on how to use cookies but can't seem to get the logic of using it to get my results

```
<a href="mylink.html" class="disabled">Download</a>
<a href="anotherlink.html" class="disabled">Delete</a>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a.disabled').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this thing using php that might be more secure.

Comment: Any working code or suggested link to explain and show how  to do in php

Comment: Are you applying this on public users or authenticated users?

Comment: It is with authenticated users

Comment: Than it's quite easy I think you have to store the datetime in a database when user clicks on download and then everytimes user gets login you have to check whether user's datetime null or not and if not than match current date is greater than 5 days of stored date if so just set a flag for that to display active link or disabled link using php.

Comment: I don't make use of database I have a password protected page for every user where password and login is saved in a <?php include("/home/xxxxxxxx/password_protect.php"); ?> file

Comment: Why you need to do that?

Comment: Prevent them from spamming a facebook fan page. I have a local fanpage where I give them the ability to post once per week there add for free and by not disabling the href link they can click multiple times on it and post the same add more than once to try and keep their add ontop in facebook

Comment: I mean to say why dont you use database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these step to check to obtain the result you desire:-

1. Now a create function as follow to take in account of the cookie:-

   `function onclickLink(event, this1){
       if($.cookie('link_disabled') === null || $.cookie('link_disabled')==undefined) {
           /* do whatever you want with link*/
           $.cookie("link_disabled", 1, { expires : 5 });/*setting the cookie for 5 days*/
       }
       else{event.preventDefault();} 
   }`
2. Modifiying current event accordingly:-

   `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(parent).on('click', 'a.disabled',function(e) {
           onclickLink(e,$(this));
       });
   });`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73vzD/211/)

This fiddle will not work chrome as chrome does not allow to set cookie locally. So here is the version of the code that is running on the server: [link](http://shoesonloose.com/cookie.html) it works in all browsers. Comment if any one faces any bug.

The plugin used is **[jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1)**

Follow these answers to know more about cookies and other stuff:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537083/3190165
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2824037/3190165

Comment: I use this [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for cookie, I have written the code according to it. you can use any other plugin also or if you want you can hard code it.

Comment: Hi, I learn by by practical experience like jsfiddle to understand the behavior of script I made a small index file referencing to:- <script src="../../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> but don't know where to place the function code herewith an example of my index.php file.

Comment: Sorry, replace above comment: Hi, I learn by by practical experience like jsfiddle to understand the behavior of script I have added <script src="../../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> in heading but don't know where to place the function and how

Comment: If it helps, I will create jsFiddle for the answer that I have written. But it would great if you share the jsfiddle you have created so that the problem can be analyzed which will help you in the future.

Comment: I haven't created a jsfiddel  Just a small php file with your code  and placed jquery.cookie.js in root directory as my file is 2 sub directories down and to see if I can understand & get code working.
 
Just don't know how to add the function code to see if it is working

In <head> 

<script src="../../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 

in <body>

<a href="http://google.co.za" target="_blank">Download</a>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('a.disabled').on('click', function(e) { 
onclickLink(e,$(this)); 
}); 
});
</script>

Comment: In <head> 

    <script src="../../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 

in <body>

    <a href="http://google.co.za" target="_blank">Download</a>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('a.disabled').on('click', function(e) { 
    onclickLink(e,$(this)); 
    }); 
    });
    </script>

Comment: I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73vzD/191/) for it. Look into it. If still you have some issues, ask me.

Comment: Just copy paste the code anywhere below calling the script jquery.cookie.js. The order of calling the script should be 1. jquery script 2. jquery.cookie.js 3. the above code written.

Comment: It will be highly appreciated if you could create js fiddel so to help me understand the scenario

Comment: I have updated the code so that it will run in all the browsers look into it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73vzD/204/)

Comment: Thaxs, work 100% I have now a more understanding of jquery cookie