# Auto Trigger a button in Javascript. Lightbox Popup in featherlight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

HTML Part

```
<a class="btn ban-default loginsignupbutton" href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1">Login/Signup</a>


<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">         
<h2>Login</h2>
<input name="loginuserphone" placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER" type="text">
<input name="loginuserpassword" placeholder="PASSWORD" type="password">
</div>
```

**What I want to do:**

actually the basic script is working fine, when user clicks on the button, the lightbox popup is coming...  but I want to AUTO open the popup,  on page loads.

**I Tried**

```
$('.loginsignupbutton').trigger('click');
```

did't worked, then i tried.

```
$('a.loginsignupbutton').featherlight({
  openTrigger:    'click',
});
```

did't worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `(!!$.cookie('token')` condition satisfy?

Comment: Yes, i actually got that solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362688/jquery-check-if-cookie-exists-if-not-create-it#comment36632491_23344706

Comment: Just keep an alert inside `if` and check if it is passing?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao oops, that function seems not be working. but still i tried just to trigger it from JS. like leaving the cookie part, just want to show that popup when page loads. even that didn't worked :(

Comment: can you try setting up an example `fiddle`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, sorry for the delay, here it is - http://codepen.io/wooranker/pen/vGQQex

Comment: Expecting it **[`like this`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/qZQQvR)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, thanks a lot :D if you are from featherlight.js and you got donate button, let me know. i'l more happy to done some thing.  one more kind request, do  featherlight.js has any ONCLOSE function ? and if possible can you kindly please implement it in that codepen, like an alert  box ONCLOSE... please.

Comment: Sorry @Yogesh.. am not that smart to build a plugin.. Just having basic knowledge on `jquery`.. Instead of onclose you have `afterClose` event. You need to look into the **[`configuration options`](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#configuration)** provided by them so that you'll get some idea..

Comment: **[`Something like this`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/qZQQvR)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, i actually tried this - http://codepen.io/wooranker/pen/VaVVxp :) ofcource not worked at all. ;) do you mind ? are you on upwork or freelancer  ? :D

Comment: Am working in a company cum `freelancer` too. I hope demo given in my last comment is what you are expecting..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao if you can share your upwork profile ;) that might help me to pay you for the work done! :) or to hire you in future to work together

Comment: Sorry Yogesh.. No upwork profile yet.. Have to create one.. If possible let me know if there are any other ways we can connect..

Comment: skype ? can i have your Skype ? you can delete the comment after I added you ;)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, let me know if you are comfortable with freelancer, you can share that profile :)

Comment: any help with this is highly appreciated.. is there any chance to get an ALERT box ONCLOSE, without changing anything in html part... http://codepen.io/wooranker/pen/VaVVxp

Comment: **[`Like this`?](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/ZWVYVL)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, do take time and check your freelancer inbox message and reply me over there bro!